# Paperback novel featuring a dragon shapeshifter, with three characters on the cover, including a princess on a throne

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

I'm looking for a book I read while incarcerated. It's a paperback novel, a little older. On the cover, it has a princess on the throne, her dark haired female warrior and sidekick male dragon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, can you tell us anything more about the plot or characters?

Comment: Was the dragon in dragon or human form on the cover?

Comment: Your prison library will have records of what was checked out (and by whom). Contacting them should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: This cover looks similar-ish to your description but not exact: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1564524205i/169873.jpg